# Not enough fingerpints on the Galaxy S6

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have the Samsung Galaxy S6. I use the fingerprint method to lock my phone. For some reason Samsung has decided that no-one will ever want to use more than 4 fingerprints. The obviously never asked my opinion on the matter.

Fingerprints used:

1. Left Thumb (when I take it out of my left pocket)
2. Right Thumb (when I take it out of my right pocket)
3. Left Index (when it's charging on my wireless charger at work)
4. Right Index (when it's on my night-stand next to my bed)
5. Wife's Left Index (or any one of her fingers) in case she needs to use my phone

I can understand that Samsung would need to limit the number of fingerprints that are stored in not, but why 4? why not 5? 10? etc

So the QUESTION is: (without rooting) How can I get 5 (or more) fingerprints stored?

1. I'm not going to start using another method to lock the phone
2. I also want my wife to be able to use the fingerprint method
3. I want to be able to use both my thumbs and both my index fingers.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already figured it out, here is how.

Tap Add Fingerprint.
Do your thumb until it reads about 50%, then just switch to your forefinger for the next 50. Heck, you can even alternate, it doesn't know the difference (but of course, it does). That's all. Maybe do your less used finger after the 80% point.

You can do multiple fingers under one name, but what I don't know for sure is one thing... if the finger scanner is dynamic. Meaning, the more you use it every day the better it gets (Fails less often). If not then I would limit it to 3 fingers per "print". If it is then you can do as many as you need.

Comment: Interesting! I'll give it a shot.